# Does Facebook Chat XMPP support XEP-0184 Extension?

Tags: facebook, xmppframework, facebook-chat

From last two days, I have been trying to find out why the hell, Facebook is not sending the message receipts. (same like "Seen" feature in Web Interface).

This is XMPPMessage I am sending to Facebook Chat XMPP Server. But Facebook is in no mood to return the receipt or acknowledgement of the message. If you can guys can guide me, it will be really helpful.

```
 <message type="chat" to="-XXXXXXXXX@chat.facebook.com" id="E32DB9A2-8D0F-4BEC-87DF-299102CC4ABF"><body>Helll</body><active xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates"/><request xmlns="urn:xmpp:receipts"/></message>
```